# Django: Map data from an external APIs into a model?

Tags: python, django, json, api, rest

I am pulling in some JSON data from various external APIs. Their data may be structured like this:

```
"game": {
    "title": "Super Mario Bros. 3",
    "release": "1989",
    "players": 3,
    ..
}
```

However, I'd like to store this directly in my database via this model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    debut = models.DateField()
    max_players = models.IntegerField()
```

As you can tell, the JSON attributes don't match up to the model's attributes.

Is there a clean way to map each attribute to easily import this data? Is it possible do do this through django's deserialization module? Or will I need to create something of my own?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create classmethod (or place it in model manager https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects):

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    debut = models.DateField()
    max_players = models.IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def create_from_j(cls, game): # assumed that game is dict already
        j2m = {'title': 'name', 'release': 'debut', 'players': 'max_players'}
        return cls(**{j2m[k]:v for k,v in game.items()})
```

just call this method then you need to create a Game from json data:

```
game = Game.create_from_j(json.loads(json_game))
```

Comment: This is a great start, thanks for the tip! By the way, is there a benefit from moving this into a model manager?

Comment: I think it is not so important. I would move this function in custom manager only if i already had one for that model

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easy way  is to write a script using python.
you may need json module to handle the data you get, convert to python object.

Then ,loop the json ,using `Game.objects.create()`to insert data to database

Comment: I thought about doing this, but i have 20+ external sources (and growing). Trying to reduce the amount manual labor and keep the code as DRY as possible.

Comment: @simonwjackson ,I have compared some ways to handle these problem,script is the most easy way.ps,this function,just supply data to your application,so keep the application clean,isolate the code unrelatd.